# Junit Test for a class which has abstract class object

Tags: java, spring, junit, dependency-injection

i am writing a Junit test case for a class which has an object of an another abstract class.

i tried to define the beans for both classes in my application context but it gives

```
 Could not instantiate bean class: Is it an abstract class?; nested exception is java.lang.InstantiationException
```

here's the situation.

my Abstract class :

```
public abstract class classA{

public returnType methodA{//method logic}
public returnType methodB{//method logic}

}
```

another class which uses abstract class object

```
public class classB {

@Autowired
classA classa;

public returnType methodB{
  variable c = classa.methodA();
  variable d = somelogic(c);
  return d
}


}
```

my applicationContextTest is

```
<bean id="classa" name="classa" class="package.classA"/>
<bean id="classb" class="package.classB">
<property name="classa" ref="classa"></property>
</bean>
```

and i have not written this classes so i have no idea why the author has not extended the abstract class and i can not make any changes in class definitions.

Autowiring works perfectly fine in application and i have enabled component scan for beans in application.
but for test application context i define bean definitions manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to "instantiate" an abstract class then there is only one solution: *use a subclass*. If the subclass doesn't exist yet, *create it*:

```
package mypackage;

public class MyClassA extends classA {
    // Implement all abstract methods here, even if it is just a dummy implementation
}
```

Your spring configuration should then read:

```
<bean id="classa" name="classa" class="mypackage.MyClassA"/>
```